# Wildfly Http interface not listening while deploying

Tags: jboss, wildfly

**Context:** I'm trying to deploy two artifacts appA.war and appB.war within the same server. During startup, appB makes an http request to appA, therefore appB.war depends of the other on startup so I declare that dependency in the jboss-all.xml

```
<jboss umlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
<jboss-deployment-dependencies xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-dependencies:1.0"
                               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:deployment-dependencies:1.0 ">
    <dependency name="appA.war"/>
</jboss-deployment-dependencies>
```

**Problem:** Dependency rule works as expected. But during container restart, http requests are rejected even if I retry infinitely. Only after wildfly is completly up the requests are processed. Looks like the interface is whether not set up or disabled during deployment scanning. I've found this on my logs

```
2021-04-24 13:52:53,846 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 2.2.5.Final starting
2021-04-24 13:52:53,967 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/opt/wildfly/develop/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
2021-04-24 13:52:53,976 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
2021-04-24 13:52:53,977 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) Queuing requests.
2021-04-24 13:52:53,978 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
2021-04-24 13:52:54,044 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 0.0.0.0:8081
2021-04-24 13:52:54,170 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYEJB0493: Jakarta Enterprise Beans subsystem suspension complete
2021-04-24 13:52:54,249 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
2021-04-24 13:52:54,324 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYPAT0050: WildFly Full cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
2021-04-24 13:52:54,352 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /opt/wildfly/develop/standalone/deployments
2021-04-24 13:52:54,356 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "appA.war" (runtime-name: "holiday.war")
2021-04-24 13:52:54,359 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "appB.war" (runtime-name: "configuracion.war")
2021-04-24 13:52:54,478 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 0.0.0.0:8444
2021-04-24 13:52:54,531 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.4.3.Final (Apache CXF 3.3.10)
```

Do you know how to solve this? or any workarround?

Answer (score 0):

It's expected behaviour that the server does not accept external connections until it's finished booting. You can alternative try

- Disable this behaviour (I would not recommend)
- start the server with no apps deployed. Then deploy one by one using the cli
- Just run two different server instances with one app each

Alternatively if you know that both apps are always on the same sever, swap to in-vm calls like making ejb calls rather than http which is much less efficient way for two items in the same jvm to communicate

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFCORE-4291 which was introduced in WF 23